# Remove contextual links inside a description tag of a feed without losing the value

Tags: php, xml, parsing, replace, feed

I would like to know if it's possible to remove all contextual links inside a <description> tag of an XML feed.

Here is what I have got inside the PHP file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $url = "http://www.Example.com/articles.rss";
    $page = file($url);

    foreach ($page as $part)
    {
        echo $part;
    }
?>
```

See screenshot of the XML feed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTsBf.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace to find links and replace them with empty lines.

Match opening `<a>` tag and then closing `</a>`:

```
foreach ($page as $part)
{
  $part = preg_replace("/<a\b[^>]*>/", "", $part);
  $part = preg_replace("/<\/a>/", "", $part);
  echo $part;
}
```

Live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/9dWWxbhzLn

Comment: Thank you for you awnser Alexander and the link ;), i have implemented your code but for some reason it is not removing the <a> tags inside the <description> tag

Comment: This gegular expression is commonly used for URLs. If you don't get any errors and <a>'s are still there, paste contents of <description> in regular expressions checker (under the given link) and play with expression. Or post <description> here, because it's pretty much hard to see anything on the screenshot ;)
Anyway, this regular expression worked for me when I've tested it.

Comment: here is the url that outputs the xml with description and the links inside.http://metroonline.nl/betribes.php

Comment: Updated answer. Watch live demo link.